# How to add serial number with products in Magento 2

Tags: product, module, configurable-product

I need to module that is able to attachment a serial number to each product sold in Magento 2

Comment: Can you provide a little more info? Are you saving the serial number to each product and then needing that info to pass to the order for each product?

Comment: Yes I want to add serial number when we place order

Comment: added how to get a product attribute from the order, not sure if you meant that you need to set the product attribute value, but that should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you how to get product info from the order using a Module / Observer:

First create your module in `app/code/Vendor/Module`

**Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php    
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Next create an event to fire after every order:

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="vendor_module_get_product_info" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\GetProductInfo"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

And lastly, create your observer that will grab your product info after every order:

**Vendor/Module/Observer/GetProductInfo.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class GetProductInfo implements ObserverInterface
{      
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    try {
      foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        // your product logic
        $item->getProductAttribute();
      }         
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      // Handle your errors
    }
  }
}
```